# Misinterpretation of Sum Variance Law

Tags: statistics, variance

I'm trying to understand how to combine variances of batches of observations. My understanding is that you can simply sum them according to the [sum variance law](https://apcentral.collegeboard.org/courses/ap-statistics/classroom-resources/why-variances-add-and-why-it-matters). But my experiments seem to differ from this theorem.

Here is the python code used:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(100000)
expected = np.var(x)
print("expected:", expected)
for n in [2,4,5,10,20,40,50,100,1000]:
    s = np.split(x, n)
    sigma_sq = [np.var(v) for v in s]
    result = np.sum(sigma_sq)
    print("result", n, ":", result, "(", np.abs(result - expected), ")")
```

the printed result is:

```
expected: 0.0832224743666757
result 2 : 0.16644455708841321 ( 0.08322208272173752 )
result 4 : 0.3328814911392468 ( 0.24965901677257113 )
result 5 : 0.4161068624507617 ( 0.33288438808408605 )
result 10 : 0.832183555011673 ( 0.7489610806449972 )
result 20 : 1.664227484757454 ( 1.5810050103907785 )
result 40 : 3.3278497945218355 ( 3.2446273201551596 )
result 50 : 4.159353197179163 ( 4.076130722812487 )
result 100 : 8.314084653397305 ( 8.23086217903063 )
result 1000 : 82.397691161862 ( 82.31446868749532 )
```

As the number of splits grows the difference between the expected and the result grows.

However if I divide the sums by `n` (i.e. average them) then the error is acceptable (on the order of `1e-5`).

I must be misinterpreting the sum variance law, but I'm not sure where my misunderstanding is.

Answer (score 0):

There are different reasons for this I think.
1. If we have a small sample -> computing the variance could be error (i.e. not really the true variance of a certain distribution).
2. There might be a chance that two samples are not totally independent.

The best way to fix these things is to have two very large samples. You can run the following code and see the variance of two lists is close to the sum of two variances. This is not the case when we replace 10000 with a smaller number, say, 10, 100, 1000.